How to rehydrate my store using createRehydrateReducer() from package ngrx-rehydrate
I use @ngrx/store. Here is my code:
.action.ts
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";

export const addPhotoToFavs = createAction("Add photo to Favorites", props<{photoID:number}>());
export const removePhotoFromFavs = createAction("Remove photo from Favorites", props<{photoID:number}>());

.reducer.ts
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { addPhotoToFavs, removePhotoFromFavs } from "./favoritePhotos.actions";
import { favoritePhotoState } from "./favoritePhotos.model";

const initialState: favoritePhotoState = {
  favoritePhotoList: [],
};

export const favoritePhotosListReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addPhotoToFavs, (state, action) =>
    ({ favoritePhotoList: [...state.favoritePhotoList, action.photoID] })
  ),
);

Now I want to use ngrx-rehydrate package from here so to be able to save and restore my data to/from localstorage.
According to Usage and Refs link to this example, supposed that just by changing the createReducer to createRehydrateReducer and adding the {key : "what-ever-key-name"} the reducer will work...
"new" .reducer.ts
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { addPhotoToFavs, removePhotoFromFavs } from "./favoritePhotos.actions";
import { favoritePhotoState } from "./favoritePhotos.model";
import { createRehydrateReducer } from "ngrx-rehydrate";

const initialState: favoritePhotoState = {
  favoritePhotoList: [],
};

export const favoritePhotosListReducer = createRehydrateReducer(
  {key : "key1"},
  initialState,
  on(addPhotoToFavs, (state, action) =>
    ({ ...state, favoritePhotoList: [...state.favoritePhotoList, action.photoID] })
  )  
 );

...but instead I get this type-errors:

Argument of type 'ReducerTypes<favoritePhotoState, [ActionCreator<"Add
photo to Favorites", (props: { photoID: number; }) => { photoID:
number; } & TypedAction<"Add photo to Favorites">>]>' is not
assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerTypes<favoritePhotoState,
ActionCreator[]>'.


Types of property 'reducer' are incompatible.

Type 'OnReducer<favoritePhotoState, [ActionCreator<"Add photo to Favorites", (props: { photoID: number; }) => { photoID: number; } &
TypedAction<"Add photo to Favorites">>], favoritePhotoState,
favoritePhotoState>' is not assignable to type
'OnReducer<favoritePhotoState, ActionCreator[]>'.



Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.

Type 'object & { type: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ photoID: number; } & TypedAction<"Add photo to Favorites"> & { type:
"Add photo to Favorites"; }'.




Property 'photoID' is missing in type '{ type: string; }' but required in type '{ photoID: number; }'.


Using Angular 17 standalone
What am I missing?

please share a stackblitz with the issue happening

@NarenMurali
I just import my project from Github to Stackblitz.
Here is the link if you want to take a look
https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/AK47-AK47/MyGalleryApp

the package has been updated (version 1.0.0), it uses Angular 18 and ngrx 18. your case was added as a test to make sure it works. thanks for using the lib.
ref

I just re install your package (1.0.0) but still I get the same error, do you clone my project and test it on my code?

sorry, but debugging your code is a bit out of my field of responsibilities. I have your actions, state and reducer working here https://github.com/amdor/ngrx-rehydrate/blob/main/test/typecheck.spec.ts i will double check if the correct code is deployed to 1.0.0 today sometime just to make sure

checked out your project, types mismatch because of required version difference. i'm using ngrx 18 (beta) now, it seems types are not that compatible with 17. upgraded it to 18 in your project locally, and it was fine immediately.

thanks for your replay and your effort.
As a last solution I just copy paste your implementation of createRehydrationReducer() localy in my .reducer.ts and leave the VS put all involved variable to :any type. This looks to work for v17 Angular( but this way I dont use your code as a dependency)

here is how I implement your function localy and use it in my project as shared via
import { createRehydrateReducer } from "../shared/create-rehydrate-reducer";
Thanks again!
